# Do databases use their own binary encodings to store data on disk? Why not use Google Protobuf?

Tags: json, database, encoding, protocol-buffers

1. What binary encodings are used by databases like SQLite 3, MySQL, PostgreSQL, etc to persist data on disk?
2. If Google Protobuf is good, why not use that to encode and store data on disk?
3. Are Google Protobuf / Facebook Thrift only helpful in network communication like microservice to another microservice?
4. Why do we not use these third party binary encoding libraries for storing data on disks?

[This blog] talks about how Protobufs beat JSON in response times.
I am confused whether these binary encoding libraries like protobuf, Avro, Thrift are only used for network communications and not for storing data on disk?

Comment: my hammer is "good" at putting in nails; it isn't a good idea to use it for driving screws, though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"good" is contextual; protobuf is "good" for x-plat general purpose data representation where that data needs to support round-trip of unexpected fields, etc; these are not the same problems that databases face. Databases usually use custom data/memory layouts based on row layouts - and the fastest way of serializing that is to just use the *exact same layout on disk* - perhaps using mmap; protobuf is not a good candidate for that, since it is variable size; databases usually want constant size (ish) so rows are deterministic within pages. Add to that transactionality etc...

Also: protobuf *can be and is* used for storing data on disk; just; not usually as part of an RDBMS.

Comment: Thanks for helping me understand the context with which to look at this question. The Google documentation says Protobuf are suitable for packets that are few megabytes in size. If that's the case, how can I use it to store GBs of data on disk? Or share 100 megabytes between inter-server communication?

Comment: @rachitiitr you can still *use* protobuf for larger payloads, although some implementations struggle as you go into the gigabyte range; note: json (tags in the question) is *also* pushing things for massive payloads - that problem doesn't magically go away

Comment: Got it, also reading a file with GB in size will take time whatever the encoding we use. But Protobuf can't support random access. FlatBuffer by Google allows to store the hierarchical data in flat buffers, so can be leveraged for random access, am I right?